# Fixing a broken RAID5 using mdmadm on Ubuntu 12.04 [QNAP device]

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

One of our QNAP NAS had gone down while alerting on disk thus they were all working/accessible on the array. And I'm trying to recover the DATA as the QNAP NAS neither boots nor responds with/without the disks.

I've booted all the HDD's using an Ubuntu live disk with **mdadm** command. I'm not sure what happened to disk one as it shows **HPFS/NTFS/exFAT** on partition 3 of one disk. Further, the **UUID* which suppose to some unique numbers are now shown as **0000:0000....** along with **Raid level: unknown**.

Below are some useful outputs that I have collected.

## fdisk -l

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fdisk -l | more

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00009a4a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              40     1060289      530125   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1060296     2120579      530142   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         2120584  1952507969   975193693    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4      1952507976  1953503999      498012   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ac6cc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              40     1060289      530125   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2         1060296     2120579      530142   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3         2120584  1952507969   975193693   83  Linux
/dev/sdb4      1952507976  1953503999      498012   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b7ac5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              40     1060289      530125   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2         1060296     2120579      530142   83  Linux
/dev/sdc3         2120584  1952507969   975193693   83  Linux
/dev/sdc4      1952507976  1953503999      498012   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000b7ac5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1              40     1060289      530125   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2         1060296     2120579      530142   83  Linux
/dev/sdc3         2120584  1952507969   975193693   83  Linux
/dev/sdc4      1952507976  1953503999      498012   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdd: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d2a20

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1              40     1060289      530125   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2         1060296     2120579      530142   83  Linux
/dev/sdd3         2120584  1952507969   975193693   83  Linux
/dev/sdd4      1952507976  1953503999      498012   83  Linux
```

## mdmadm examine

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mdadm -E /dev/sd[abcd]3
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
  Creation Time : Fri Sep 25 07:04:44 2015
     Raid Level : -unknown-
   Raid Devices : 0
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri Sep 25 07:19:04 2015
          State : active
 Active Devices : 0
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 3
       Checksum : 8f463afd - correct
         Events : 1


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8        3        2      spare   /dev/sda3

   0     0       8       35        0      spare   /dev/sdc3
   1     1       8       19        1      spare   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8        3        2      spare   /dev/sda3
/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
  Creation Time : Fri Sep 25 07:04:44 2015
     Raid Level : -unknown-
   Raid Devices : 0
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri Sep 25 07:19:04 2015
          State : active
 Active Devices : 0
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 3
       Checksum : 8f463b19 - correct
         Events : 1


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       35        0      spare   /dev/sdc3

   0     0       8       35        0      spare   /dev/sdc3
   1     1       8       19        1      spare   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8        3        2      spare   /dev/sda3
/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
  Creation Time : Fri Sep 25 07:04:44 2015
     Raid Level : -unknown-
   Raid Devices : 0
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri Sep 25 07:19:04 2015
          State : active
 Active Devices : 0
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 3
       Checksum : 8f463b0b - correct
         Events : 1


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       19        1      spare   /dev/sdb3

   0     0       8       35        0      spare   /dev/sdc3
   1     1       8       19        1      spare   /dev/sdb3
   2     2       8        3        2      spare   /dev/sda3
/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
  Creation Time : Fri Sep 25 09:28:22 2015
     Raid Level : -unknown-
   Raid Devices : 0
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Fri Sep 25 09:31:03 2015
          State : active
 Active Devices : 0
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : 8f467b40 - correct
         Events : 1


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8        3        0      spare   /dev/sda3

   0     0       8        3        0      spare   /dev/sda3
```

## mdadm conf

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf 
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md4 UUID=a5ef83a2:3df739b9:7e77f235:9827a98f
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
   spares=3
ARRAY /dev/md9 UUID=c39aa918:f8de04d3:bb375993:177a40db
ARRAY /dev/md4 UUID=bb500a60:f1f7edde:07b598b5:09c70531
   spares=1
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=00000000:00000000:00000000:00000000
   spares=1
ARRAY /dev/md13 UUID=62a22532:1a265501:07a38901:1b2b353e

# This file was auto-generated on Sat, 26 Sep 2015 05:23:53 +0000
# by mkconf $Id$
```

## mdstat after issuing and assemble command

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```

Can someone point out what have I done wrong here, or am I missing something?

I'm really stuck with this and if anyone could help to retrieve DATA by pulling back the RAID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I do not want to leave this question open forever. So, I'm posting an answer to close this off.

This was completely screwed by one of my colleague and it was almost ripped off the moment I had taken this. Due to some recovery applications used without knowing that the drives are actually on a RAID array, it had totally lost it ID's and parities. This was confirmed by the **QNAP** techs when they took a remove session.

However, I was able to see only QNAP related DATA as they were in a different partition on the drives. I was able to combine the RAID arrays and mount the DATA as well.

Final outcome was to rebuild using **mdadm** with `--create` which might help or leave me no choice. However, I did not succeed on that which pretty much proves that the arrays are lost and disks are gone.

No choice but to bear the pain. Here I close my thread.

A complete research and command that I had used can be found in "**[Fixing a broken QNAP RAID5 using mdmadm on Ubuntu 12.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296471)**". Hopefully, someone might find a clue or two if they ever come across such a situation.